# ForceTouch / Tap & Hold animation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, uigesturerecognizer

I have a button that the user has to hold to perform its action.

When the user touch the button initially an animation should start and update the frame and colour of a given view

While the user is still holding the button after some time (2 seconds) the long press should be recognised and a new animation should take place

When the user releases the button we need to update the view to reset its original constraints and:

1. if not recognised : do nothing (for now)
2. if recognised : perform the action (unhide a view)

I tried `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` but I didn't manage to get the status before the long press is recognised

I tried nesting `UIViewAnimations` and stoping them with `view.layer.removeAllAnimations()` but some animations was not being removed (I suspect the cycle of callbacks)

The effect, created on an apple watch, is what I want to recreate on my iphone app: http://natashatherobot.com/wp-content/uploads/MenuDemo.mp4

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I cant tell you how to do it in swift but the way i would go about it is this. When you press the button the 1st anim starts. Now in the 1st anim you set a 2 senond timer. Using the (UILongPressGestureRecognizer , minimumPressDuration) you set a flag (true/false). In the 1st 
Anim after 2sec if the Flag is true play the 2nd animation if false dont. You sould then perform further actions with the false flag